# Column count stacking when there is no content

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have looked around but couldn't find anything describing my problem. I have 5 section elements in a main tag with 3 of them containing text and images.

I'm trying to get each section in a column side by side using column count, however the last two columns with no text and images stack instead of remaining next to each other. I have attached a picture below.

When I add the same images and text it works as it should but I would like to know if I can have empty columns as I do not have content for them yet.

[image]

**The Code:**

```css
main {
     -webkit-column-count: 5; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 5; /* Firefox */
     column-count: 5;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.office {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.office_border {
  border: 2px solid #95cccc;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}
.office_title {
  font: normal 1.9rem DIN;
}
.office_properties {
  padding: 0;
}
.office_properties_title {
  font: 0.8rem 'Josefin Sans';
}
.office_properties_title_text {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.office_properties_item_image {
  width: 100%;
}
.office_properties_button {
  padding: 5%;
}
.office_properties_link {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c0392b;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section class="office">
        <h1 class="office_title">TITLE</h1>
        <ul class="office_properties">
            <div class="office_border"></div>
            <li class="office_properties_title">
                <h2 class="office_properties_title_text">Heading</h2>
            </li>
            <li class="office_properties_item">
                <a href=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="" class="office_properties_item_image"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="office_properties_button">
                <a href="" class="office_properties_link">DISCOVER</a>
            </li>
            <div class="office_border"></div>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="office">
        <h1 class="office_title">TITLE</h1>
        <ul class="office_properties">
            <div class="office_border"></div>
            <li class="office_properties_title">
                <h2 class="office_properties_title_text">Heading</h2>
            </li>
            <li class="office_properties_item">
                <a href=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="" class="office_properties_item_image"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="office_properties_button">
                <a href="" class="office_properties_link">DISCOVER</a>
            </li>
            <div class="office_border"></div>
            <li class="office_properties_title">
                <h2 class="office_properties_title_text">Heading</h2>
            </li>
            <li class="office_properties_item">
                <a href=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="" class="office_properties_item_image"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="office_properties_button">
                <a href="" class="office_properties_link">DISCOVER</a>
            </li>
            <div class="office_border"></div>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="office">
        <h1 class="office_title">TITLE</h1>
        <ul class="office_properties">
            <div class="office_border"></div>
            <li class="office_properties_title">
                <h2 class="office_properties_title_text">Heading</h2>
            </li>
            <li class="office_properties_item">
                <a href=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="" class="office_properties_item_image"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="office_properties_button">
                <a href="" class="office_properties_link">DISCOVER</a>
            </li>
            <div class="office_border"></div>
            <li class="office_properties_title">
                <h2 class="office_properties_title_text">Heading</h2>
            </li>
            <li class="office_properties_item">
                <a href=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="" class="office_properties_item_image"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="office_properties_button">
                <a href="" class="office_properties_link">DISCOVER</a>
            </li>
            <div class="office_border"></div>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="office">
        <h1 class="office_title">TITLE</h1>
        <ul class="office_properties">
            <div class="office_border"></div>
            <li class="office_properties_title"> </li>
            <li class="office_properties_item"> </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="office">
        <h1 class="office_title">TITLE</h1>
        <ul class="office_properties">
            <div class="office_border"></div>
            <li class="office_properties_title"> </li>
            <li class="office_properties_item"> </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Can you adjust the code so that it is more accurate to the scenario you described?

Comment: Sure, I just thought it might be too long with all the html

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:inline-flex` to main you can also find an example I made [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u1d0v80r/), also I added support for column-count for other browsers.
If you want to watch it in the snippet click on "full page".
I hope this help:)

```css
main {
  display:inline-flex;
    -webkit-column-count: 5; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 5; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 5;
    
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.office {
    margin-top: 5%;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.office_border {
    border: 2px solid #95cccc;
    width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
}

.office_title {
    font: normal 1.9rem DIN;
}

.office_properties {
    padding: 0;
}

.office_properties_title {
    font: 0.8rem 'Josefin Sans';
}

.office_properties_title_text {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.office_properties_item_image {
    width: 100%;
}

.office_properties_button {
    padding: 5%;
}

.office_properties_link {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c0392b;
}
```

```html
  <main>
        <section class="office">
            <h1 class="office_title">TITLE</h1>
            <ul class="office_properties">
                <div class="office_border"></div>
                <li class="office_properties_title">
                    <h2 class="office_properties_title_text">Heading</h2>
                </li>
                <li class="office_properties_item">
                    <a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/Strokkur_21_(js).jpg/668px-Strokkur_21_(js).jpg" alt="" class="office_properties_item_image"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="office_properties_button">
                    <a href="" class="office_properties_link">DISCOVER</a>
                </li>
                <div class="office_border"></div>
            </ul>
        </section>
         <section class="office">
            <h1 class="office_title">TITLE</h1>
            <ul class="office_properties">
                <div class="office_border"></div>
                <li class="office_properties_title">
                    <h2 class="office_properties_title_text">Heading</h2>
                </li>
                <li class="office_properties_item">
                    <a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/Strokkur_21_(js).jpg/668px-Strokkur_21_(js).jpg" alt="" class="office_properties_item_image"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="office_properties_button">
                    <a href="" class="office_properties_link">DISCOVER</a>
                </li>
                <div class="office_border"></div>
            </ul>
        </section>
         <section class="office">
            <h1 class="office_title">TITLE</h1>
            <ul class="office_properties">
                <div class="office_border"></div>
                <li class="office_properties_title">
                    <h2 class="office_properties_title_text">Heading</h2>
                </li>
                <li class="office_properties_item">
                    <a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/Strokkur_21_(js).jpg/668px-Strokkur_21_(js).jpg" alt="" class="office_properties_item_image"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="office_properties_button">
                    <a href="" class="office_properties_link">DISCOVER</a>
                </li>
                <div class="office_border"></div>
            </ul>
        </section>
         <section class="office">
            <h1 class="office_title">TITLE</h1>
            <ul class="office_properties">
                <div class="office_border"></div>
                <li class="office_properties_title">
                    <h2 class="office_properties_title_text">Heading</h2>
                </li>
                <li class="office_properties_item">
                    <a href=""><img src="assets/properties/21JS.jpg" alt="" class="office_properties_item_image"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="office_properties_button">
                    <a href="" class="office_properties_link">DISCOVER</a>
                </li>
                <div class="office_border"></div>
            </ul>
        </section>
         <section class="office">
            <h1 class="office_title">TITLE</h1>
            <ul class="office_properties">
                <div class="office_border"></div>
                <li class="office_properties_title">
                    <h2 class="office_properties_title_text">Heading</h2>
                </li>
                <li class="office_properties_item">
                    <a href=""><img src="assets/properties/21JS.jpg" alt="" class="office_properties_item_image"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="office_properties_button">
                    <a href="" class="office_properties_link">DISCOVER</a>
                </li>
                <div class="office_border"></div>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </main>
```

Comment: Thanks yes that works, is it possible without using flexbox? does column count have to have a certain amount of content for it to be respected?